# vb.net I can't answer a simple loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop

I had a project to do with looping a text into vertical and horizontal

suppose to look like this
http://pastebin.com/UJ6LZybU

Please help me :(
well this are the code i tried
but it only showed the end of the words

```
    Dim input As String = "HELLOWORLD"
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    For i = 0 To input.Length - 1
        Dim words As Char = input(i)
        TextBox1.Text = ("HELLOWORLD" & vbNewLine & words)
    Next
```

this project can be answered in any type of loop
doloop
forloop

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @SLaks i failed on the vertical part, it only showed end of the words which is "D"

Comment: @dbasnett the textbox multiline has already been enabled. and yes i already resize the textbox earlier :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set TextBox1.Multiline = True and resize

```
    Dim input As String = "HELLOWORLD"

    TextBox1.Text = ("HELLOWORLD" & Environment.NewLine)
    For i As Integer = 1 To input.Length - 1
        TextBox1.Text &= (input(i) & Environment.NewLine)
    Next
```

Comment: HOLY dark water! THANK YOU, you don't know how this mean to me..! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim input As String = "HELLOWORLD"
TextBox1.Text = input 

For i = 1 To input.Length - 1
    TextBox1.Text &= vbNewLine & input(i)
Next
```

Comment: can i ask , what is "&="